# vim netrw-mc on remote filesystem

Tags: vim, sftp, netrw

I'd like transfer file within vim netrw plugin from a remote host to my machine.

I tried to do the following:

within netrw I set a local destination directory with netrw-mt,
I connect to remote host with `:e sftp://remoteuser@remotehost/path/` 
and with netrw-mf choose files to copy.
When I hit netrw-mc for starting copy nothing happens.

Is  my procedure  bugged or it only works between local directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able make it working by using `:e scp://remoteuser@remotehost/path/`.

The reason because this one worked and the `:e sftp://remoteuser@remotehost/path/` did not it's a mystery on my Linux CrunchBang "Waldorf" #11 both on netrw 142 and 149.

Comment: You might want to report this to Dr Chip; he's very open to feedback and keep to improve his plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are fine. Following your instructions, I just successfully copied a file from a remote `scp://` link to the local system (local is GVIM 7.3.823 with netrw v150h, remote a Ubuntu 13.04 server).

Be sure to try out the [latest development version](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW); Dr Chip continually improves his plugins.

For further troubleshooting (and to potentially contact the author with the problem), see `:help netrw-debug`.

Comment: It seems that is not version dependant at least it's the same both on 142 and 149